# How do I make links that have been published to Facebook via the Feed Dialog stop asking users to authorize my application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

So here is the deal: I am working on a web app that includes a Facebook Connect option, but that's not the only way to sign up or log in.

I have a button to share the page you're on. It opens a Feed Dialog to publish the link to the user's feed. At no point in this process is the user being asked to authorize my application, which is correct.

But then if I go back to Facebook and click on the link, it asks the user to authorize my application. I don't want that. How does one make that stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off authenticated referrals in your app settings

Comment: Seems so obvious now! (A co-worker had set this, and I didn't know about it.)